# Import and parse a .csv file with multiple data blocks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a .csv file with 15 data blocks (each block is separated by two rows of zeros). Each block is 16x16.

I would like to import this into a cell in MATLAB so I can easily access each individual block for analysis. Here is what I have tried so far, but `fgetl` and `fgets` remove the matrix format and also do not give me the individual cells I want.

```
fileID_cos = fopen('variable_brillouin_cos.csv');

Block = 1;

while (~feof(fileID_cos))
    fprintf('Block: %s\n', num2str(Block))  % Print block number to the screen
    InputText = fgetl(fileID_cos);
    comp = strcmp(InputText,'0');
    if comp == 0
       Data{Block,1} = InputText;
       Block = Block + 1;                   % Increment block index
    else
       % Do nothing - don't read
    end                                   

end
```

I tried messing around with `textscan` as well, but I am not too sure how to get that to work. I was following the example here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/reading-arbitrary-format-text-files-with-textscan.html

EDIT: Here is an excerpt of the first two data blocks from my .csv file (2x3x16):

> 0.9992287094   0   0
>
> -0.0014847289  0.0582334756    0
>
> -0.0342878228  0.007099638 0.0460434373
>
> 0.005238545    -0.014102395    -0.0064428952
>
> 0.0041854498   0.0016727184    -0.0063756844
>
> -0.0010147738  0.0025424322    0.0019445089
>
> -0.0008249775  -0.00102181 0.0011112002
>
> 0.0002007113   -0.0003419567   -0.000332161
>
> 0.0002909916   6.47733298552847E-05    -0.000372398
>
> -4.97697754763672E-05  2.53135160405396E-05    1.37384469745553E-05
>
> -6.69268915155018E-05  5.17541889751699E-05    0.000115002
>
> -2.25078759011089E-05  -9.4409769330572E-05    4.519931558177E-05
>
> 5.07028561121694E-05   -7.32595335398115E-05   -7.90541160988023E-05
>
> 2.52228828927873E-05   3.13998660159052E-05    -3.59807082625053E-05
>
> -2.26997218734607E-05  8.41379631611071E-06    3.2902284592782E-05
>
> -0.000019695   -4.86435490970069E-05   2.58425361765046E-05
>
> 0  0   0
>
> 0  0   0
>
> 0.9952580275   0   0
>
> -0.0014741309  0.0577730556    0
>
> -0.0338816221  0.0070146088    0.0454970609
>
> 0.0051560767   -0.0138844528   -0.0063416486
>
> 0.0041060663   0.0016393367    -0.0062540706
>
> -0.0009919008  0.0024819681    0.0018997603
>
> -0.0008019338  -0.0009956338   0.0010798323
>
> 0.0001948589   -0.0003332688   -0.0003221603
>
> 0.0002816506   6.2320254232888E-05 -0.0003605357
>
> -4.87388321597287E-05  2.29788680538837E-05    1.42137144094536E-05
>
> -6.35666587570066E-05  4.81815519669417E-05    0.000109376
>
> -2.13596699829001E-05  -9.08958604638168E-05   4.25332719521993E-05
>
> 4.85046575990093E-05   -6.99485838406453E-05   -7.55865872986199E-05
>
> 2.32942086120719E-05   2.81906152684917E-05    -3.33507607030521E-05
>
> -2.07229114591174E-05  6.79039983723664E-06    3.01930791396076E-05
>
> -1.85259428148148E-05  -4.62398737406514E-05   2.3827396784366E-05

Comment: why you don't use [`csvread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html)?

Comment: Can you please add few lines from your *.csv file or upload an example .csv somewhere?

Comment: @A_C `csvread` imports the entire .csv file, correct? I want to be able to read in line by line the data file so I can access each data block individually

Comment: @Lati I edited my post to include an excerpt of the data file. Hopefully that makes things more clear

Comment: @Stella  I think that if you use it with the synthax `M = csvread(filename,R1,C1,[R1 C1 R2 C2])` like in the documentation, it should work.

Comment: Apparently all your lines have 3 numbers, so i would just import the file in one go (with `csvread` or `dlmread`), then it will be easier to separate your blocks from a global matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, you have tried the example from here:

[Reading Arbitrary Format Text Files with TEXTSCAN](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/reading-arbitrary-format-text-files-with-textscan.html)

This would work if you would have just one line of zeros to separate the blocks. Or you need to add some codes to check adjacent rows of zeros.

For your case, I have tried following:

```
fileID_cos = fopen('variable_brillouin_cos.csv');
%initialize the array
dataCell = {};
% initialize counters
zeroCheck = 0;
counterCol = 1;
counterRow = 1;
lineNumber = 0;
lineNumberZeroLine = 0;


while (~feof(fileID_cos))
    %fprintf('Block: %s\n', num2str(counterCol ))  % Print block number to the screen
    InputText = fgetl(fileID_cos);

    % get the data. the last number represents the number of column in your
    % csv file
    currentLineData = sscanf(InputText, '%f', 3);

    % current line number
    lineNumber = lineNumber + 1;

   % check adjacent zero rows  
    if (sum(currentLineData) == 0) && zeroCheck == 0

        zeroCheck = zeroCheck + 1;
        lineNumberZeroLine = lineNumber;

    elseif ((sum(currentLineData) == 0) && zeroCheck == 1)        
        % if adjacent
        if ((lineNumber - lineNumberZeroLine) == 1)
            zeroCheck = zeroCheck + 1;
            lineNumberZeroLine = 0;
        else
            zeroCheck = 0;
            lineNumberZeroLine = lineNumber;
        end
    end

    % if two rows of zero encountered
    if (zeroCheck ~= 2)
        dataCell{counterRow,counterCol} = currentLineData;

        counterRow = counterRow + 1;
    else
        % if all blocks have same number of rows, use following line
        % which removes the last row of the cell array
%         dataCell(counterRow -1,:) = [];       

        % reset & modify counters
        counterCol = counterCol + 1;
        zeroCheck = 0;
        counterRow = 1;
    end        

end

fclose(fileID_cos);
```

Each column of the result cell array *dataCell* is one block. When you are using your cell array, ignore the last row (in your example, ignore the 17th row in cell array. Check the comments in the code to remove this row).

Code looks a bit complicated because of counters but it works :)